# Is git a good tool to make backups?

Tags: linux, git, github

I would like to use git in my project to make backups. The question is whether it is possible to do add/commit automatically each lets say 4 hours? Should one write a kind of bash script for this or such feature has already been implemented in git?

Comment: The whole point of git is to have an accurate history of your changes.  Don't do that.

Comment: Could you explain this point in more details please? What do you mean after "accurate"

Comment: You should be committing by hand when you have a concrete change, with a meaningful message.

Comment: So git is not a tool to save a current state of the project. It is to manage versions only, isn't it?

Comment: @freude It's for managing changes, mostly by several persons working on the same projects at the same time. It's not a backup tool. You can use it as one if you want, but why make your life difficult when there are real backup tools out there.

Comment: Could you give me some examples of such backup tools, please?

Comment: @freude A popular one is http://www.dirvish.org. There are others, of course. Google is your friend :-)

Comment: dirvish.org do not create backup of the project's source code, it concerns filesystem backups

Comment: @freude Having a backup is a side-effect of version control. But it's not automated (since it doesn't have to be), so it's not really convenient for that purpose.

Comment: @freude "Filesystem backup" is a description that serves to differentiate it from "partition image backup". You can backup a single directory tree (that of your source code) if you want.

Comment: https://github.com/bup/bup, a Git-based backup tool.

Comment: @Mechanical_snail Looks very cool, but a little unfinished. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not run in the background. It only runs when you call it. Therefore it has no way to monitor how much time is passing and automatically commit.

If you need that functionality, you can create a script that does it and add it to your hourly cron jobs. The script is responsible for figuring out if 4 hours have passed since the last time it was called. The script would also be responsible for dealing with commit conflicts. How it would do that, I've no idea.

With that being said, it seems to me that you are confusing version control with incremental backups.

Answer (score 1):

You should commit only when your program reaches a stable point (e.g., it compiles).

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to implement the script for autocommit. But I'm pretty sure it will be nightmare to work with history and resolve conflicts. 
May look like following:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "autocommit"
```